# Built-in all() function not returning True on a list of negative numbers

Tags: python, built-in

Why?  Shouldn't this be True?

```
>>> sub = [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6]
>>> print all(sub) < 0
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`all(sub)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) returns `True` because all the elements of `sub` are nonzero.
`True` is not less than zero.
Therefore `all(sub) < 0` is false.

If you want to test if all elements of `sub` are negative, you would do this:

```
all(x < 0 for x in sub)
```

Answer (score 2):

@khelwood's answer is correct. However, you could also use numpy for what you want.

```
sub = np.asarray(sub)
np.all(sub<0)
```

Comment: Yes, that's why I referred to correct answer. However, a lot of scripts already have numpy imported, in which case this is probably the better solution.